# scons fails to compile

Tags: c++, windows, scons

I am trying to compile clingo from source. Which is said that it can be built under windows. scons can find my mingw toolchain but fails to run them. (Environment variables set correctly and SConscript - env variable includes paths) Here is generated debug.py and debug.log files.

debug.log

```
scons: Configure: Checking whether the C++ compiler works... 
.sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp <-
  |
  |int main()
  |{
  |    return 0;
  |}
  |
g++ /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_2.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp -std=c++11 -O0 -g -Wall -W -pedantic /nologo
g++: error: /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_2.obj: No such file or directory
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error: /nologo: No such file or directory
scons: Configure: no
```

debug.py

```
CXX = 'g++'
CXXFLAGS = ['-std=c++11', '-O0', '-g', '-Wall', '-W', '-pedantic']
CPPPATH = []
CPPDEFINES = {}
LIBS = []
LIBPATH = []
LINKFLAGS = ['-std=c++11', '-O0']
RPATH = []
AR = 'lib'
ARFLAGS = ['/nologo']
BISON = 'bison'
RE2C = 're2c'
PYTHON_CONFIG = 'python-config'
PKG_CONFIG = 'pkg-config'
WITH_PYTHON = 'auto'
WITH_LUA = 'auto'
WITH_TBB = 'auto'
WITH_CPPUNIT = 'auto'
```

Comment: It seems that SCons are adding flags used for the Visual Studio compiler. Is SCons set up correctly? Are you running from a Windows console window (i.e. a "DOS prompt")? Are you running from an emulated Unix environemnt (like Cygwin or MinGW console)?

Comment: I run "scons" in win32 command promp

Comment: I've just tried vs command promp. No luck with it either.

Comment: Did you try running from mingw shell?